# Django Custom user CustomUserManager won't save my extra data field

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a issue with my custom user model, I am creating a api with DjangoRestFrameork, django-allauth and Django-restauth
and when I create a new user with this Json for exemple to my API

{
    "email": "user@email.com",
    "first_name": "jack",
    "last_name": "mister",
    "password1": "password123",
    "password2": "password123",
    "profile_type": "individu",
    "identite_number": "23ewfwewfwe234234"
}
it's save Only email and password and not my another field

My Django Model :

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['profile_type', 'identite_number', ]

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    GROUPE = 'groupe'
    ASSOCIATION = 'association'
    INDIVIDU = 'individu'
    INDUSTRY = 'industry'

    USER_PROFILE_CHOICE = [
        (GROUPE, 'groupe'),
        (ASSOCIATION, 'association'),
        (INDIVIDU, 'individu'),
        (INDUSTRY, 'industry'),

    ]
    identificator = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=20)
    profile_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=12,
        choices=USER_PROFILE_CHOICE,
        default=INDIVIDU,
    )
    identite_number = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=20)
    identity_scan = models.FileField(blank=True)
```

My Django manager

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
       """

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)

        user = self.model(email=email, profile_type=extra_fields.get('profile_type'),
                          identite_number=extra_fields.get('identite_number'), **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

PS : I noticed, that when for example I enter a wrong email it's raise the default error of Django not mine ValueError(_('The Email must be set')

thank and sorry for my bas English .

Comment: You receive an error I guess?

Comment: Something like `TypeError: CustomUser() got multiple values for keyword argument 'identite_number'`?

Comment: no I receive any error it's save normally

Comment: and the issue is when for example I enter a wrong email it's raise the default error of Django not mine ValueError(_('The Email must be set')

Comment: it looks like you did not register your user model properly.

Comment: but the put and patch work normally, is it a problem with the view